# Java 8: RegExp - range with various separators

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regexp expression to validate the following pattern:

```
ABC
```

Note: ABC is NOT here a regExp but used to simply the description of the problem

**With**

```
Block | Accepted values              |
------+------------------------------+
A     | Any number between 1 and 11  |
B     | , or - or |                  |
C     | Any number between 1 and 11  |
```

**Comments**

1. `,` : enumerated some exact values
2. `-` : express a range
3. `|` : one value or the other
4. These symbols can be mixed (e.g. `2,3 | 1-9 | 10-11`)

**Examples**

*Valid expressions*

```
1
9,10
9,10,11|1-5
1-11
8|10
1|3|7
etc..
```

*Invalid expressions*

```
0
20
9,10,15
1-19
1|12
1|11,
etc..
```

**Tried**

```java
public class RuleTest {

    String A = "[1-9]|1[0-1]";
    String B = "[\\,\\-\\|]";
    String C = "[1-9]|1[0-1]";

    Pattern RULE_DROP_DIGIT = Pattern.compile(A+"|"+A+B+C);

    @Test
    public void mustPassRuledropdigitPatternTest() {
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("1").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("1-9").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("10-11").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("1|9").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("10|11").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("1,9").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("10,11").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("9,10,11|1-5").matches());
        assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("3|5|7").matches());
    }

    @Test
    public void mustFailRuledropdigitPatternTest() {
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, ""));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "  "));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "0"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "14"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1--9"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1--19"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "10--11"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1||9"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1||19"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "10||11"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1,,9"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "1,,19"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "10,,11"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "0,1"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "12"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, "8,"));
        assertTrue(catchedAssertionError(RULE_DROP_DIGIT, ",8"));
    }

    /*
     * Catch AssertionError
     */
    private boolean catchedAssertionError(Pattern code, CharSequence input) {
        try {
            assertTrue(code.matcher(input).matches());
            return false;
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            // NOTHING
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. What's wrong with my regular expression ?
2. What could be the correct one ?

EDIT1: Corrected A,B
EDIT2: Added note

Comment: a bit strange `A = "[1-9]|[1-9]1[0-1]"` - why the second `[1-9]`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Was originally `[1-9]|1[0-1]`. Corrected. Thanks !

Comment: You say you want to match the pattern *ABC* but it seems that you allow *A* and *ABCBCBC*.  What is the high-level structure you want to match?  Why the distinction between *A* and *C* if you want to allow an arbitrary number of *B*'s?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks. For the simplicity, A, B and C can be repeated. Still, edited to A|ABC+

Comment: there are few invalid input in your must pass pattern test like 3|5|7 , 9,10,11|1-5 and even number 19. Are these expected to pass ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange, maybe `A(BA)*`?  Per RegExp operator precedence, `A|ABC+` specifies the sequence (`A`, `ABC`, `ABCC`, `ABCCC`, ...).

Comment: @Deep Definitely. Noticed it. Thanks

Comment: @MikeSamuel My point wasn't to provide a regexp at this stage, but to show a high level pattern. Should I have express the right expression, I would have almost solve the problem ;)

Comment: as @MikeSamuel suggested Use the pattern like   Pattern.compile("^(" + A + ")((" + B + ")(" + C + "))*?$");

Comment: @Deep, I don't think the lazy quantifier in `*?` adds anything.

Comment: @MikeSamuel yes i overdid it. i think Pattern.compile("^(" + A + ")((" + B + ")(" + C + "))*$") this is enough.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange, fair enough.  If you want a quick rule of thumb, order of precedence is `|` < adjacency < (`*`, `+`, `?`, `{...}`).  And `(?:foo)` parenthesizes `foo` without affecting capturing group numbers.

Comment: I feel like a [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) would explain your desired input much better than a regex or pseudo-regex.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#manifest-specification) for an example.

Comment: At the end `"^(" + A + ")((" + B + ")(" + C + "))*$"` looks like ABC initially stated  (but different values :) . The initial intend while expressing the problem . Still, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to check with a regular expression that the left hand side of a range is less than or equal to the right hand side.

That said:

```
^(?:0*(?:1[01]|[1-9]))(?:[,\-|]0*(?:1[01]|[1-9]))*$
```

from

```
String A = "(?:0*(?:1[01]|[1-9]))";
String B = "[,\\-|]";

Pattern.compile("^" + A + "(?:" + B + A + ")*$");
```

Derivation:

> ```
> A     | Any number between 1 and 11  |
> ```

```
0*(?:1[01]|[1-9])
```

> ```
> B     | , or - or |                  |
> ```

```
[,\-|]
```

> ```
> C     | Any number between 1 and 11  |
> ```

```
0*(?:1[01]|[1-9])
```

---

In your original code:

> ```
> String A = "[1-9]|[1-9]1[0-1]";
> ```

The second `[1-9]` will cause this to not match 10 or 11, but will match many numbers between 110 and 911.

Also, be aware that when not explicitly matching `^...$` (for example using `.find()` instead of `.matches()`) then having the `[1-9]` first will cause it to match only the second `'1'` in `11`.

> ```
> Pattern RULE_DROP_DIGIT = Pattern.compile(A+"|"+A+B+C);
> ```

`A`, `B`, and `C` aren't parenthesized so the `"|"` is at the same level as the `|` in `A`.

One way to solve this is to add parentheses.

```
Pattern RULE_DROP_DIGIT = Pattern.compile("(?:"+A+")|(?:"+A+B+C+")");
```

Comment: The unit test fails at the first assertion (`assertTrue(RULE_DROP_DIGIT.matcher("1").matches())` despite escaping the separators

Comment: @HeyStackExchange, I adjusted to make the separator and right number optional.

Comment: Thanks. Its very close to the solution and I can work from that. So up voted. But expression such as `9,10,11|1-5` or `3|5|7` won't pass the validation.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange, per our discussion on your question, I rewrote to allow an arbitrary number of BC pairs.

Comment: Great Thanks. Work like a charm Marked as answered